# Swift 2 - Visualizing an AVMutableComposition for Debugging : Converting Apple's AVCompositionDebugViewer

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

I'm running into an issue with my swift 2 conversion of an Apple provided example for displaying an AVMutableComposition. This is a really useful project if you're trying to visualize your AVComposition to see what might be going on under the hood.

---

**Update:** I added print statements to each function to see the order they are being called, and who is calling them, in comparison to the Obj-C project.

Two Issues that I'm seeing that seem pretty important:

1. `synchronizePlayerWithEditor()` is not getting called after buildTransitionComposition(_:andVideoComposition:andAudioMix:)
2. `observeValueForKeyPath(_:...)` is NOT being called in the same order as the Obj-C project

Posting the snippet here to get the calling function as it's kind of useful

Obj-C

`NSLog(@"%d %s %@", __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [[NSThread callStackSymbols] objectAtIndex:1]);`

Swift

```
func functionnYouWantToPrintCaller(yourNormalParameters..., function:String = __FUNCTION__){...}
print("\(__LINE__) \(__FUNCTION__) \(function)
```

---

Here is Apple's AVCompositionDebugViewer project I'm working from: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVCompositionDebugViewer

My github repo:
https://github.com/justinlevi/iOSAVCompositionDebugViewerSwift

I *think* the issue might be stemming from something in the keyValueObservation code although I'm not entirely sure at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being in `SimpleEditor.swift`buildCompositionObjectsForPlayback` method. There were some global variables that were being defined incorrectly.

Everything seems to be working as expected now. 
https://github.com/justinlevi/iOSAVCompositionDebugViewerSwift